# How to solve the duplicated key value error in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In scripts I create database with some data and use there **bulk_save_objects**. After then i trying ro add new record to db without explicitly indicating id, i get error **duplicated key value**
Some code from my scripts:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
room = Room(id=1, name='room', size=0, floor=0)
db.bulk_save_objects([room])
```

and more saving with more models.
My api for add bew record to db, in payload id not specified:

```
room = Room(**payload.dict())
db.add(room)
db.commit()
```

Model:

```
class Room(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rooms'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    size = Column(Float)
    floor = Column(Integer)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: So what does your Room model look like? Unless you have a default and auto incrementing value as the standard for your Room model, you will always assign a NULL value as the id (or the default value for the field). That will work with the first object, but not any after that.

Comment: @MatsLindh in all models i sen column id wirh primary key True, i tryied delete ids in scipts, create with db.add but nothing helped. The problem is that sqlalchemy does not see changes in the database and automatically sets the value for the id field to 1, although there are already 10 records in the database.

Comment: Having just `primary_key=True` does not make it automagically assign a value, you'll either need to generate one through `default` or use `auto_increment=True` for the fields. In your example you're _always_ trying to add a room with id=1 regardless, I assume you only run this command with an empty database?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yea to create db with some data, tried with autoincrement true didnt work(

Answer (score 0):

`payload["id"]`, assuming it's there, should be set to None, or leave that keyname omitted since your DB can assign the primary key during the write time

Comment: In payload id not specified